Как контролировать работу suggest
Я создаю объект suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest-string');
Как я могу проконтролировать превышение лимита запросов для suggest api

Статистику можно получить через веб-интерфейс или API Кабинета разработчика.
Чтобы получить информацию о текущем лимите, выполните последовательно запросы:
— на получение идентификаторов существующих проектов
— на получение идентификаторов сервисов с использованием полученного выше project_id
— итоговый запрос о статистике с использованием полученных project_id и service_id.
Полная инструкция есть в документации.
